# Ionic & Angular: Toggle CSS throughout the entire app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

New to Angular so forgive me. How would you accomplish something in the vein of a 'Night Mode' in which you can toggle between two CSS states that's then represented in all of the views?

Take for instance:

View 1:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-bar></ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-positive" ng-click="activeButton();">Night Mode</ion-toggle>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

View 2:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-bar></ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <div ng-class="'active' : isActive">Change Me!</div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

JS:

```
classApp.controller('classCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isActive = false;
  $scope.activeButton = function() {
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
  }  
});
```

CSS:

```
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

This doesn't work naturally. It only does if the element(s) being changed are in the same view, but what if I want to change the CSS of an element that's in one view from another? Even if they use the same controller it doesn't seem to matter.

I've read a couple of questions on here about using a service to pass variables between two controllers, would this have any relevance my question?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you have a Main Controller ? because you can put the method `$scope.activeButton` there to access in the entire application, and the variable `$scope.isActive`maybe can be a rootScope variable like this `$rootScope.isActive`, remember inject the $rootScope dependency in every controller you want to access to the active value.

Comment: That appears to have done the trick! You've saved me a lot of bother thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @Naxes, I put my comment as a response of this question , please mark it as a valid response for those who has the same question, greetings !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Main Controller you can put the method `$scope.activeButton` there to access in the entire application, and the variable `$scope.isActivemaybe` can be a rootScope variable like this `$rootScope.isActive`, remember inject the `$rootScope` dependency in every controller you want to access to the active value